# How to get a single contour that represents multiple contours of a same object using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection

I have several images that captured the same object and I want to find the average contour. The object position slightly changed across the images, so the contours of the images does not completely overlap, as shown in the picture (blue dots; red line is what I want to get).

[image]

I used `cv2.findContours` to find the outlines of the object, and each contour has different different number of points.

I've tried to make the points into a heatmap-like image and try to find the contour of the image after applying gaussian filter, but it was not a continuous line but rather multiple blobs that the function detected:

[image]
Does anyone have a good idea how to find a single line of the object?

Comment: Can you also share your actual, unannotated image without axes please?

Comment: What did your data look like at the previous steps of your processing please? I suspect you might get to where you want to go more simply/reliably if you started out differently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape

Comment: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/timothy.f.cootes/Papers/cviu95.pdf
This might help. You could also look into active contour models and apply it to the heatmap.